# Apache POI merged Region/CellRangeAddress with wrapText not wrapping text in whole area

Tags: apache, merge, apache-poi

So i'm trying to merge for example 3 rows and 30 cells each row. It merges, but if I add cellStyle wrapText, it wraps text only in first row, not in whole merged region.. Spent like 2 days trying to figure how to do this, but no success. POI version is 3.5, but I have tried latest stable one too and in neither it works.

```
copyRowCells(reminderSheet, newSheet, 0, newSheetRow, 4, 39);
copyRowCells(reminderSheet, newSheet, 1, newSheetRow + 1, 4, 39);
copyRowCells(reminderSheet, newSheet, 2, newSheetRow + 2, 4, 39);
copyRowCells(reminderSheet, newSheet, 3, newSheetRow + 3, 4, 39);

cell = cellFind(newSheet, "[event_text]");

mergeCells(newSheet, newSheetRow + 1, newSheetRow + 3, 4, 33);

HSSFCell cellOrigin = cellFind(reminderSheet, "[event_text]");

cell.getCellStyle().cloneStyleFrom(cellOrigin.getCellStyle());

cell.setCellValue(text);
```

Comment: Can you post some code that you are using?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.